# Mostrar titulos con foreach

Tags: c#

La cuestión es esta: 
Estoy haciendo un programa en windows form que genere 10 tarjetas (con un ciclo) pero tambien necesito hacer un arreglo con los titulos de estas tarjetas para modificarlas solamente modificando la posición del arreglo, el problema es que o solo me muestra la primera letra o no me muestra nada. Les comparto el codigo

```
private void InitComponent()
    {
        var titulo = new string[10];
        titulo[0] = "titulo1";
        titulo[1] = "titulo2";
        titulo[2] = "titulo3";
        titulo[3] = "titulo4";
        titulo[4] = "titulo5";
        titulo[5] = "titulo6";
        titulo[6] = "titulo7";
        titulo[7] = "titulo8";
        titulo[8] = "titulo9";
        titulo[9] = "titulo10";

        this._contenedor = new Panel();
        _contenedor.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        _contenedor.Size = new Size(800,550);
        //_contenedor.BackColor = Color.Black;
        _contenedor.AutoScroll = true;
        this.Controls.Add(_contenedor);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            foreach (var tit in titulo[i])
            {
            this._tarjeta = new Componentes.Tarjeta(new Size(700, 150), Image.FromHbitmap(Properties.Resources.maxresdefault.GetHbitmap()), ""+tit, "Parrafo" + (i + 1), new Point(50, (i * 180)));
            _contenedor.Controls.Add(_tarjeta);
                _tarjeta.Titulo.Text = tit.ToString();

                Button ubi = new Button()
                {
                Location = new Point(550, 100),
                Text = "Ubicacion",
                Width = 90,
                Height = 24,
                };
            _tarjeta.Controls.Add(ubi);
            this._tarjeta.AutoScroll = true;

            }   

        }       
    }
```

Comment: Porque estas utilizando un `for` fuera de un `foreach`? con el _foreach_ debería ser suficiente...

Comment: Sí, lo siento, estaba de más. Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y la primera instrucción era crear las 10 tarjetas y lo primero que se me ocurrió fue usar el for y sinceramente se me paso eliminarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando vas a crear objeto dentro de un `foreach` no definas la variable de forma global, porque en cada iteracion vas a pisar al anterior

```
int i=0;
foreach (var tit in titulo[i])
{
    Componentes.Tarjeta tarjeta = new Componentes.Tarjeta(new Size(700, 150), Image.FromHbitmap(Properties.Resources.maxresdefault.GetHbitmap()), ""+tit, "Parrafo" + (i + 1), new Point(50, (i * 180)));

    tarjeta.Titulo.Text = tit.ToString();

    Button ubi = new Button()
    {
        Location = new Point(550, 100),
        Text = "Ubicacion",
        Width = 90,
        Height = 24,
    };
    tarjeta.Controls.Add(ubi);
    tarjeta.AutoScroll = true;

    _contenedor.Controls.Add(tarjeta);
    i++;
}
```

No necesitas hacer un `for` para tener la variable `i` con solo iterar el array alcanza

Como observaras la variable tarjata tiene un ambito local al `foreach`